# Laravel order process, includes a different file for each step of order process. On click to go to next step will sometimes refresh the page

Tags: php, laravel, session, switch-statement

So on our CRM we have an order process, it goes along the lines of:
Initiate Call > Pitch > Order > Enter Details > Payment. 
Each one of these steps has a different file which is PHP included and each file, when the next button is clicked, will change a status variable which is switched through in Laravel in a switch case statement.

My issue is that sometimes when the next button is clicked on one step, it will refresh the page and restart the order process. We use session variables quite a lot during this process so we think it might be a session issue.

Any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Difficult without code. I would like to see how you transition with session to see if there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Due to rapid developer turn around there has been many different contributors to the code, so fair warning, it is a bit of a mess. Which part of the code would you like to see? I can show you the switch case?

Comment: The part where you manipulate the session and transition to the next step.

Comment: So each include (step) has a form within it which posts a hidden input with a value of the current step with the name 'origin' , then in our controller we have a switch that looks like this:
`if (isset($_POST['Origin'])) {
 switch ($_POST['Origin']) {
case "Initial":
$status = 1;
break; `

Sorry, not sure how to format code properly in comments on here! 

So once the $status is set, after the switch case the $status variable is stored in a session variable for the view to access.

Comment: The status variable is returned to the view like this:
`return Redirect::back()->with('status', $status);`

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. Easier to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137150/discussion-between-sam-fullen-and-eddythedove).

Answer (score 0):

In the controller

```
public function step(Request $request) {
    $step = 1;

    if ( $request->has('step') && $request->step != '' ) {
        $step = $request->step + 1;
    }

    //do some other stuff
    ...

    //don't do the following 
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', $status); //<-- if the page is refreshed. this is gone. 

    //we need to manually put it in the session 
    session(['status' => $status]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

In the view

```
@php $status = session('status') @endphp

@if( 1 == $status ) 
    @include('steps.one')
@elseif( 2 == $status )
    @include('steps.two')
    ...
@endif
```